How could I have the same result in polars for pd.ExcelFile
I want to have the same result than pd.ExcelFile in polars.
pd.ExcelFile has a dataframe object. But, if I want to write the same script in polars and I use pl.read_excel, I have dataframe not the object dataframe.
I have an excel and I use the script below to read the data.
excel_data = BytesIO(response["Body"].read())

With pandas I use this :
result1 = pd.ExcelFile(excel_data)

I want to use polars but I don't have the same result. If you have an idea. Thank to share it with me.

Assuming you want to achieve roughly the same functionality as this pandas example:
>>> file = pd.ExcelFile('myfile.xlsx')  
>>> with pd.ExcelFile("myfile.xls") as xls:  
...     df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, "Sheet1")  

Then with polars you can do for example this:
import polars as pl

dataframes = pl.read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_id=0)

for sheet, frame in dataframes.items():
    print(sheet)
    print(frame.head())

When passing 0 to sheet_id, you get a dictionary of { sheet_name : dataframe } pairs, which you can then do whatever you want with.
However, you don't really specify what exactly you do with pd.ExcelFile that you cannot reproduce with polars, so it's hard to say if this answers your question.
